# Cambiar el color a marco y líneas de un icono/span

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Quiero trabajar con este span (`navbar-toggler-icon`) en bootstrap 4. Quiero cambiarle el color tanto al marco como a las líneas. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="index.html" class="nav-link active ml-1 mr-1">Inicio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="conocenos.html" class="nav-link active ml-1               
      mr-1">Conócenos</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active ml-1 mr-1" href="servicios.html" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data- toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> 
      Servicios</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="clasescachorros.html">Clases de 
        cachorros</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="adiestramiento.html">Adiestramiento 
        básico y avanzado</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="perrosbusqueda.html">Perros de 
        búsqueda</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="malasconductas.html">Modificacion de 
        malas conductas</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="cursos.html">Cursos</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active ml-1 mr-1" href="galeria.html" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data- toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Galería</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria- labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="fotos.html">Fotos</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="videos.html">Vídeos</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="contacto.html" class="nav-link active ml-1 mr-
      1">Contacto</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hola Marcos. Al codigo que has añadido vas a tener que poner las referencias a bootstrap. Al editar la pregunta, abajo del todo tendrás un "editar este fragmento de código" y luego añades la etiqueta `<script>` para la referencia. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Para cambiar el color del marco (el cuadrado) la clase es `.navbar-toggler`, entonces puedes cambiar el color de fondo y el borde de la siguiente manera (podrías hacerlo más genérico solamente con `.navbar-toggler` pero podrías tener problemas de especificidad):

```
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
  background-color: #007bff;
  border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.85);
}
```

Luego mirando el código de las barras en el CSS, se está usando una imagen SVG inline, entonces para cambiar el color podrías copiar el estilo CSS y cambiar el color de las líneas (cambiando el valor de `stroke`). La clase es `.navbar-toggler-icon` (podrías hacerla más genérica como indicaba arriba):

```
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler  .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 30 30' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

---

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando, el botón cambia de blanco con las líneas grises a azul con las líneas blancas:

```css
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
  background-color: #007bff;
  border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.85);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler  .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 30 30' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="index.html" class="nav-link active ml-1 mr-1">Inicio</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="conocenos.html" class="nav-link active ml-1               
      mr-1">Conócenos</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active ml-1 mr-1" href="servicios.html" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data- toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> 
      Servicios</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="clasescachorros.html">Clases de 
        cachorros</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="adiestramiento.html">Adiestramiento 
        básico y avanzado</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="perrosbusqueda.html">Perros de 
        búsqueda</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="malasconductas.html">Modificacion de 
        malas conductas</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="cursos.html">Cursos</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle active ml-1 mr-1" href="galeria.html" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data- toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Galería</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria- labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="fotos.html">Fotos</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="videos.html">Vídeos</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="contacto.html" class="nav-link active ml-1 mr-
      1">Contacto</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```